# Why do we have to emphasize std while sorting an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Why do we have to put std when sorting an array via begin and end iterators when that's not the case with vector,list etc?

example:

```
std::sort( std::begin(array), std::end(array), [](int a,int b) { return a>b;} );
```

Comment: it's namespace.

Comment: By "array" do you mean a `std::array` or a C-style `int[]`?

Comment: @NathanPierson on some platforms, it could be either

Comment: Actually I guess I'm not sure what's being asked. Is it why _sort_ needs the `std` prefix? I initially read it as "why do I have to write `std::begin(array)` instead of `some_vector.begin()`?" I'd love an example of what the baseline `vector` version looks like.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/vTb8ToE5K

Answer (score 6):

This is due to [argument dependant lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). That `vector`'s iterators allow you to omit `std::` is not guaranteed by the standard, but it is a fairly common implementation detail.

If the result type of `std::vector::begin()` is a class type defined in `std`, then `sort(vec.begin(), vec.end())` will look in `std` for `sort` as well as the global namespace, and finds `std::sort` (and nothing in the global namespace).

The result of `std::begin(array)` is a pointer, which is not a type from `std`, so `sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array))` only looks in the global namespace, and doesn't find any functions there.

Comment: also note it doesn't need `std::` for `begin`/`end`.

Comment: @appleapple it does if `array` is a `[]` array, and doesn't if it is a `std::array`

Comment: true. I was meant to say `std::begin(vector)`, now I see you mean `array` as the raw array/std::array version